# How to write code for delete file from external memory

Tags: java, android, file

I use this code for delete file from external memory.But it can not delete("Not Deleted").How can I do?

Main class

```
public void deleteButtonClicked(View v) {
    deleteExternalStoragePrivateFile();
}

private void deleteExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
    File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    if (path != null) {

        if(getApplicationContext().deleteFile("OneRepublic_-_Something_I_Need.mp3"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your deleteFile method details pls

Comment: I use getApplicationContext().deleteFile("OneRepublic_-_Something_I_Need.mp3") for delete.But I'm not sure does it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code for delete

```
    private void deleteExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
    File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    if (path != null) {

        if (path.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : path.listFiles()) {
                String child1 = child.toString();
                if (child1.contains("OneRepublic_-_Something_I_Need.mp3")) {
                    child.delete();
                }
                if (child.isDirectory()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can say your issue must be simple so just explain we will fix.

Comment: error "f path.listFiles()"  and can not use "child"

Comment: Did you check my edit?. Your variable name path. "f" i mistakenly type so remove it

Comment: oh sorry but it error just one "child.isDirectory" can not use child

Comment: Ok i understand your issue.

Comment: My mistake. Now check my edited answer. You need to move if and else inside of the loop.  Did you really want that toast?

Comment: can not use .isDirectory and the first "if" error,it error after condition in first if

Comment: Ok just use the code now i updated. No changes needed.

Comment: Yess, It work now.Thank you,But If I need to delete all file How canI do?

Comment: If you want to delete all files then just remove this if condition if (child1.contains("OneRepublic_-_Something_I_Need.mp3"))

Answer (score 1):

`Context.deleteFile("")`  deletes the given file associated with this Context's application package.

If you wanna delete a file you can use this code. Here is the [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-delete-file-in-java/) for the actual source.

```
public void deleteFile(String[] args)
    {   
        try{

            File file = new File("c:\\logfile20100131.log");

            if(file.delete()){
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
            }

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the necessary permissions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you are indeed having the permissions, you can use file.delete() as suggested in other answers.

**Edit:**

```
private void deleteExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
File path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
if (path != null) {

    for(File f:path.listFiles()){
        String name = f.getName();
        if(name.contains("OneRepublic_-_Something_I_Need.mp3")){
            if(f.delete())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi... can you please try the code that I have added? And also, please try printing `path.getName()` to make sure that the path that you are pointing to is indeed the correct path where the file is stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Find base directory - file
File file = getApplicationContext()
        .getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdirs();
}

//Find your file path
File filePath = new File(file, YOUR_FILE_NAME);

//Delete your file
if(! filePath.exists())
    return;
else
    filePath.delete();
```

Make sure you have added following permissions in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: It not working  I use your code and sure that I following permissions